# Weather API forecast_hourly suddenly returning "1" in iconName

Tags: here-api

The Weather API forecast_hourly has started within the last 24 hours to incorrectly return a value of "1" in the iconName member instead of a string such as "clear", for some entries. It contains the value of the deprecated "icon" member I guess. It seems to be for multiple conditions - the textual descriptions vary - passing clouds, more sun than clouds, etc.

You can see it in the response of this example request:

https://weather.ls.hereapi.com/weather/1.0/report.json?product=forecast_hourly&latitude=55.606416&longitude=12.589923&metric=true&hourlyDate=2020-11-02&language=en&apikey=

Answer (score 0):

Could you please test it again, this is working as expected.

In general you can check the current status of services on our statsus page here: https://status.here.com/status